# Symbolizing values when GeoServer published GeoTiff is all black?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I am new to GeoServer. I'm using the latest version as of time of post on windows 10 running as a windows service.

I have published a single geotif. Each pixes has a value between 0 and 7, and I want to see each value as a color in the Raster. When I add the geotif to ArcMap, somehow ArcMap knows what the colors are.

How do I tell geoserver to do symbology on a Raster (Geotif file on my local disk)?

Comment: Why don't you simply read the [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide a `Style` other than the default raster style (which just uses a linear stretch between black and white). See the [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/rasters.html) for examples of raster styling.